# Solving a Matrix Equation with Maple

Tags: maple

I am attempting to use Maple to solve a matrix equation of the form $aB^2 + bB + cI = B^{-2}$, where $B$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix, and I is the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix (i.e. to find the values a, b and c which satisfy the equation).

My idea was to use a piece of code like

```
A:=Matrix([[7,4,-2],[4,7,5],[2,-3,8]]);
d:=Vector([[8],[5],[2]]);
```

for matrix inversion to solve a system of three linear equations but that would assume that the right-hand side of the equation is a column vector when it is actually another $3 \times 3$ matrix.  Is there a  simple way to look at this which I am missing?

Comment: I don't know anything about Maple, but I do know that at worse you could translate this problem into a simultaneous system of $27$ equations with $3$ unknowns by simply computing coordinate-wise. I would hope that Maple would have something within that which would not force you to do this, but ultimately it would work.

Comment: I was hoping there might be something in the linear algebra package with Maple: could you provide a bit more information on how I would follow your approach?

Comment: Sure. An equality between 3x3 matrices is also an equality between all the entries of those matrices. So compute the matrix entries for $B^2$ and $B^{-2}$, and then look at the equality for all the $(1,1)$ coordinates, and all the $(1,2)$ coordinates, and so on, for each of the matrices. If there is a solution, then a solution will be found very quickly.

Comment: Not to worry, I've mentioned to solve it now: I used something like your suggestion, it was just a case of writing the code to get Maple to do it.

Answer (score 1):

using new letters, there is the characteristic polynomial for $B.$ As $B$ is 3 by 3 and invertible, we have $r \neq 0$ in
$$ B^3 + p B^2 + q B + r I = 0.   $$
When needed, this gives us the useful $$  B^3 = -p B^2 - q B - r I .   $$
Next, we get
$$ B^4 =  -p B^3 - q B^2 - r B = -p (-p B^2 - q B - r I )  - q B^2 - r B ,   $$ 
$$  B^4 = (p^2 - q) B^2 + (pq -r)B + prI. $$
Looks right. For you, these coefficients will be integers.
Also, you should confirm with the actual numbers that show up.

Back to $ B^3 + p B^2 + q B + r I = 0,   $ we have $r \neq 0$ in
$$  B^3 + p B^2 + q B = -rI,  $$
$$ B^2 + p B + q I = -r B^{-1}. $$ So
$$ B^{-1} = - \frac{1}{r} B^2 - \frac{p}{r} B - \frac{q}{r} I.  $$
Nice rational coefficients, no guesswork. Finally, we get $B^{-2} = \left(B^{-1} \right)^2,$ which involves those coefficients, and will have $B^4$ and $B^3.$ All you do is substitute the expressions we found for $B^4$ and $B^3,$ add like terms, you get $B^{-2}$ in terms of $B^2, B,I.$

Comment: I have tried this but end up getting a bit of a mess, although everything is in terms of $B^2$, $B$ and $I$ and I can have 0 on the right hand side if I move $B^{-2}$ to the left-hand side, how do I then use this to find $q$, $p$ and $r$ given values for the entries of $B$, $I$ and $B^2$ and the original equation $qB^2 + pB + rI = B^{-2}$ ?